# GLSL Compilation error ... only when running through gDEBugger

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am loading some shaders using the code

```
std::string progSource;
std::ifstream infile;
infile.open(shaderPath);
std::string line;
while(std::getline(infile,line))
  progSource+=line+'\n';
int fileSize = progSource.size();
const char* s = progSource.c_str();
glShaderSource(ShaderObj, 1, &s, NULL);
```

and this works fine (I am loading vertex, geometry and fragment shaders).  Then I try to load a tessellation shader, and in MSVC++ and when running the exe, it is perfectly happy.  However, when I run it through gDEBugger, it crashes with the oh-so-helpful `error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $end at token "(EOF)"` error.

Any idea what is causing this?  Does gDEBugger not support tesselation shaders, perhaps?  If so, can anyone suggest a nice alternative?

Answer (score 3):

GDebugger is not maintained anymore and supports up to OpenGL 3.1 which doesn't have tessellation shaders.